# I have 2 keyboards PSR E353 and PSR I455. Can I connect them both in a midi setup?

Tags: midi, keyboard, setup

I have Yamaha Psr E353 and I455. Both have no midi ports in them.  But the i455 has a USB port for a thumb drive. I am hoping if in any possible way the both keyboards be linked to form a rack. And so I can transfer midi thru them to FL Studio?

This question is because I want to sell my 353 but i have no responses on it. It's barely old. So if there is a possibility that I can connect them both to use for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "USB TO DEVICE" connector is not useful for real-time MIDI.

Both keyboards have a "USB TO HOST" connector, which can be connected only to a PC.
So if you want to link them, you have to do this with software on the PC. (This typically requires a "virtual MIDI" driver.)

Comment: Latency is gonna kill ya.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if I have 2 USB cables (USB to host cable) and connect them both separately to PC. I can use them both right?

Comment: When you connect them to the PC, software on the PC can use them. You still need the right software.